# Access denied when trying to open hosts file on Windows 10, even as administrator

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm using windows 10 home. The hosts file in the etc folder initially opened when double clicked, but not sure what/or if i accidentally changed something, because now it says access denied, every time, regardless if trying to open it as administrator or not. However, what i notice, if it matters, is the file permissions check boxes are checked differently between the properties > security window and the properties > security > edit button window. One has read & execute and read greyed out, while the latter has all permissions checked the same, 'Allow'. Pls see attached pics, and i'm wondering if those indicate why the file access is being denied, and if so, how to change it back so that file access is allowed. Thanks,

wouldn't allow me to post the images, showing different check boxes for file permissions checked

Comment: FYI: You mention attached pictures but there aren't any showing.

Comment: “because now it says access denied, every time, regardless if trying to open it as administrator or not.” - This behavior is intentional. Open Notepad as an Administrator then within Notepad open the hosts file.

Comment: thanks, btw, as mentioned in my question, couldn't add pictures, as it requires rating of 10 or something..

Comment: when opening hosts from within notepad as administrator, the dialogue box instead reads "You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission."

Comment: You can still attach pic, they just show as links that can be clicked to view. Please do thisn